# jQuery action that selects multiple `div`s

Tags: jquery, html, performance

On my page I display multiple videos using the following code:

```
<div class="video-block">
    <div class="video-profile-inactive">{profile}</div>
    <div class="video-banned-inactive">{banned}</div>
</div>
```

Some videos has a class "video-profile-active" or "video-banned-active". But they have only one class at a time. Both the classes are not possible.

When my page is loading I am looking for the first `div` who have both classes as 'inactive', like the example above.

I've added this in jQuery

```
$(".btn-profiled-inactive, .btn-banned-inactive").first();
```

but does not work.

Does anyone know how can I search through all the `div`s with class 'video-block' and who have both `div`s with the classes 'video-profile-inactive' and 'video-banned-inactive'?

Example:

```
<div class="video-block">
    <div class="video-profile-active" data-v-id="1" data-c-id="4">active profile video1</div>
    <div class="video-banned-inactive">inactive banned video1</div>
</div>

<div class="video-block">
    <div class="video-profile-inactive" data-v-id="2" data-c-id="4">inactive profile video2</div>
    <div class="video-banned-active">active banned video2</div>
</div>

<div class="video-block">
    <div class="video-profile-inactive" data-v-id="3" data-c-id="4">inactive profile video3</div>
    <div class="video-banned-active">active banned video3</div>
</div>

<div class="video-block">
    <div class="video-profile-inactive" data-v-id="4" data-c-id="4">inactive profile video4</div>
    <div class="video-banned-inactive">inactive banned video4</div>
</div>
```

In this case, video4 meets the criteria because both classes are inactive. The question is now how I can find this in jQuery and receive the data-c-id and data-v-id.

Comment: If you want to select by multiple classes, join them together in the selector: `$(".btn-profiled-inactive.btn-banned-inactive")`

Comment: See my answer, I think I understood what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood right, you want the first `.video-block` that has 2 inactive divs.

```
$(".video-profile-inactive").next().each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("video-banned-inactive")) {
      //parentDiv is the .video-block that has 2 inactive divs
      var parentDiv = $(this).parent('.video-block');
      var data1 = $(this).prev().attr('data-v-id');
      var data2 = $(this).prev().attr('data-c-id');
      alert(data1);
      alert(data2);     
      return false;
    }
});
```

I have a JSFiddle with some mixed divs: https://jsfiddle.net/vnqtxya5/33/

`.attr('data-v-id')` will get your values.

If you don't return false on the loop, it will add the class to all `.video-block` that have 2 inactive divs.

Answer (score 0):

To get all divs which has `video-block` class then you can get using

```
$('.video-block');
```

and if you want to get the div which has  `video-profile-inactive` and `video-banned-inactive` then can get using following code

```
$('.video-profile-inactive.video-banned-inactive');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your english the question is unclear. I think you wanted to say the first `div` with `class` `.btn-profiled-inactive` and first div with class `.btn-banned-inactive`. If so you can do it this way.

```
$(".btn-profiled-inactive").first(); 

$(".btn-banned-inactive").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector

```
$(".video-block > .video-profile-inactive + .video-banned-inactive").first()
```